# How to enable hibernation for ALL power actions (button, idle, lid-close) on 21.10?

Tags: power-management, laptop, 21.10, gnome-power-manager

I'm installing Ubuntu 21.10 [along side Windows 10](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-10-dual-boot) on an HP Probook G10 which is [not supported](https://ubuntu.com/certified?q=PROBOOK&limit=13&category=Laptop&vendor=HP).  Since suspend isn't supported, and crashes when attempted, I went ahead and [manually enabled hibernation](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/) which seems to work fine.  Now I'm trying to move all power actions from the default of suspend to the only working option of hibernation.  [I tried some old methods](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/automatic-shutdown-hibernate-on-idle-ubuntu/), but they don't seem to work anymore with 21.10

I tried to set this under the "settings" panel from the Ubuntu desktop (battery icon, top right), but there is no action for lid-close.  It seems to only offer "Automatic suspend".  I was able to use to old procedure to enable power-button hibernate though.  Still doesn't fix lid-close though

[image]

I tried setting it in `gsettings` which seems to stick, but the settings don't seem to effect lid-close, despite what it reports

[image]

I tried the same in `dconf` which just showed what `gsettings` did, and still had no effect on lid-close, despite what it reports.

[image]

Despite the settings, system still attempts (and fails) `suspend` / `standby` when I close the lid.  Until I can find a "good" fix, I simply replaced `systemd-suspend.service` file with `systemd-hibernate.service` file, but I wasn't sure if that would "catch them all"?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The lid close action is now handled by systemd, configurable in /etc/systemd/logind.conf. You can set:

```
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=hibernate
HandleLidSwitchDocked=hibernate
```

to trigger hibernation for when the lid is closed on battery, on AC power, and when docked, respectively.

From `man logind.conf`:

> HandlePowerKey=, HandleSuspendKey=, HandleHibernateKey=, HandleLidSwitch=, HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=, HandleLidSwitchDocked=, HandleRebootKey=
>
> Controls how logind shall handle the system power, reboot and sleep keys and the lid switch to trigger actions such as system power-off, reboot or suspend. Can be one of "ignore", "poweroff", "reboot", "halt", "kexec", "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", "suspend-then-hibernate", and "lock". If "ignore", logind will never handle these keys. If "lock", all running sessions will be screen-locked; otherwise, the specified action will be taken in the respective event. Only input devices with the "power-switch" udev tag will be watched for key/lid switch events.  HandlePowerKey= defaults to "poweroff", HandleRebootKey= defaults to "reboot".  HandleSuspendKey= and HandleLidSwitch= default to "suspend".  HandleLidSwitchExternalPower= is completely ignored by default (for backwards compatibility) — an explicit value must be set before it will be used to determine behaviour.  HandleLidSwitchDocked= defaults to "ignore". HandleHibernateKey= defaults to "hibernate". If the system is inserted in a docking station, or if more than one display is connected, the action specified by HandleLidSwitchDocked= occurs; if the system is on external power the action (if any) specified by HandleLidSwitchExternalPower= occurs; otherwise the HandleLidSwitch= action occurs.

You can also follow this tutorial: [How to Change Lid Close Behavior in Ubuntu 20.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/lid-close-behavior-ubuntu-20-04/).